# Ne04j Graph Nodes, Expand a spanning tree but stop at specific node (but don't stop for other nodes)

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, spanning-tree

I have the following setup

1. Person is part of an organisation
2. Person attends meeting
3. Meeting is held in a location

- More than one person can attend a meeting
- More than one person can be part of same organisation
- Persons from different organisation can attend same meeting
- Multiple meeting can be held at same location

Of all the locations, there is a very oft-used one (the home base).

Meaning that when I "Expand a spanning Tree", and when I hit that location, my graph "explodes"

Example code I use:

```
MATCH (p:Person {pcode: 123456})
MATCH (terminator:Location) WHERE terminator.LocCode = 1

CALL apoc.path.spanningTree(p, {
minLevel: 1,
maxLevel: 3,
terminatorNodes: terminator
})
YIELD path
RETURN path
;
```

My hope when using terminatorNodes is that the path would stop at that particular node and ignore everything that's "beyond" .. but that's not what happens, in actual fact I see all the nodes "beyond"

I have tried using endNodes too, but there it looks like the code bombs out as soon as it bumps into that particular node and stops spanning trees everywhere else too!

I would like to obtain the same effect for a particular organisation too (mine!) but one step at a time!

What I am really trying to achieve is to retrieve all Persons connected to a starting person via meetings.
I.e. "Start Person" A attends a meeting with another 3 people from different organisations, then I want to see those Persons returned, and their organisation, and then all the people linked to their organisation.
The above is just a start, in the sense that I have other Node labels to deal with but with the same aim.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use a depth search in your case?

```
MATCH path = (p:Person {pcode: 123456})-[:RELATIONSHIP_NAME*1..3]->(terminator:Loaction)  
WHERE terminator.LocCode = 1   
RETURN path
```

Comment: Thanks for that - it didn't quite work, but most likely because I did not set out that problem well enough.
I will create a set of anonimised sample data with associated cypher queries before reposting!